# rails has_many and belongs_To

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing an app in which I have two models, User and post, so far my app has been running fine without using has_many and belongs_to accordingly. What difference is it going to make when I add these two statements? I want to see practical differences not just theory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practical improvement is that you can use the associations in your controllers without worrying about how you implemented the relationship.

For example, at present if you want to see all the posts that belong to a user `this_user` you must be doing...

```
@posts = Post.where(user_id: this_user.id)
```

With a has_many and belongs_to relationship defined you can do...

```
@posts = this_user.posts
```

This is not just trivial... if in future you change your application to have "users have many conversations, a conversation has many posts" you may end up specifying that "user has_many posts, through: conversations"

And your...

```
@posts = this_user.posts
```

STILL works, without needing to know that the details of how that relationship connects has changed

Comment: aha interesting stuff. Thanks man